# Is returning HTML directly for an Ajax response best avoided?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm starting to do some JS/HTML/CSS.  From looking around, it seems that it's not unusual to return HTML from the back-end (for example, an Ajax response) and directly display it (such as by assigning it to an element's innerHTML).  For example, I believe that the jQuery load() method basically is a shortcut to do this.

Taking the approach worries me for a couple of reasons, but I'm not sure if it's just that I'm not familiar with the approaches and idioms in these areas and I am just behind the times or whether these are legitimate concerns.  My concerns specifically are:

1) It seems insecure to directly assign HTML to an element.  Or, at a minimum, dangerous at least if there's a possibility of any user content (or even third-party content).

2) Sending presentation information (HTML) directly seems like it could likely lead to presentation/model mixing that is best avoided.  Of course, it would be possible to have these cleanly separated on the back-end and still return HTML, but on the handful of projects that I've seen that hasn't been the case.

So, my question is, is returning HTML a legitimate form of HTTP response in an Ajax app or is it best avoided?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the use case to be honest. There is a fairly heafty penalty to be paid on the client if it has to construct a lot of HTML based on some JSON or XML data.

Personally I use a mixture of both - if it's just a small bit of data (an integer or a small string) I'll use JSON or even just the raw data on its own.

If its a complicated set of data (say a bunch of user comments) that I'm going to have to format on the client side then I'll just send the html and save the client the work.

Personally I wouldn't worry about security, at least not users injecting malicious HTML - you should be dealing with that when it's submitted anyway.

Edit: There is an exception to this - when bandwidth is a concern (mobile web, for instance) then sending as little data over the wire is nearly always best.

Comment: Thanks!  Great point about mobile.  I agree about trying to filter input on submit, but I don't think that it can be done completely, because the context that it will be used it can't always be known - could be an HTML, JS, or CSS context (for example).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see right or wrong way to do this, it depends on the ammount of data you are sending and how fast you want it rendered. Inserting HTML directly *is* faster than building elements from JSON or XML. XSS should not be an issue because you should be escaping user data regardless of the format you're sending it in.

If you take a look at Facebook, all XHR responses (as far as I saw, I only started looking when I saw your question :) are something like:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":"\u003cdiv class=\"ego_column\">\u003cdiv 
class=\"ego_section\">\u003cdiv class=\"uiHeader uiHeaderTopAndBottomBorder 
mbs uiSideHeader\">\u003cdiv class=\"clearfix uiHeaderTop\">\u003ca 
class=\"uiHeaderActions rfloat\" href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/campaign\
/landing.php?placement=advf2&amp;campaign_id=368901427978&amp;extra_1=auto\">
Create an Ad\u003c\/a>\u003cdiv>\u003ch4 class=\"uiHeaderTitle\">Sponsored
\u003c\/h4> [...]" }
```

Their AJAX is content-heavy, so it probably pays off for them to send HTML. Probably their achitecture deals with structure-presentation separation.

Comment: Interesting.  The infinite loop at the beginning ('for (;;);') must be to prevent JSON hijacking, which I vaguely recall reading about.  Yes, the output should always be escaped, but returning HTML doesn't leave any room for errors in that regard, while it seems like using the DOM API.  But I'm sure that Facebook is very careful about it.